# Waiting time is high when using window.location.href OR .assign or .reload

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location, location-href

I'm using JavaScript redirects after ajax call (after update content). I've tried below methods, all are very slow. In Network tab it shows waiting time is around **4.44** to **5** seconds. (Which is very frustrating for customers :( )

```
window.location.assign(to_redirect);
window.location.replace(to_redirect);
location.href= to_redirect; 
window.location.href= to_redirect; 
window.location = to_redirect;
```

**W**hile browsing site from page to page (with mouse clicks) it's waiting time is **350ms** to **450ms**.

Why is that so ? Is there anything that I've missed or any other way that is faster?

### UPDATE:

As per request by commenter here below is a screenshot.

#### By clicking link of page, normal way.

[image]

#### After saving data and redirecting with JavaScript way.

[image]

Comment: can you give a sample of URLs that you are using?

Comment: e.g. my site is `https://www.example.com/` and I'm redirecting to `https://www.example.com/media/`

Comment: try `location.href="/media"`

Comment: same results `4.67s` :o

Comment: Use chrome or FF and use the dev tools - look at the network / timings to see where the delay is coming from.

Comment: I'm using both, chrome dev tools and Firebug, delay is coming from server `waiting time`, receiving time is too low. strange thing is that while surfing site waiting time is ~400ms.

Comment: I think more information is required here. Can you explain what is slow exactly? Does the screen go blank for 5 seconds and then load? Does nothing happen for 5 seconds and then it loads? A screenshot of the network tab that shows the problem might be useful. I also sometimes like to use a tool like wireshark to see what's going on on the wire and where the delay is. Also: What do you use server side? Maybe the problem is there?

Comment: @jlh see updated question, notice waiting time.

Comment: The TTFB value means "Time to first byte". That's the time it waits for the server to send its first byte of the response. It looks like your problem is server-side, i.e. it's whatever happens on the server that is causing this delay.

Comment: If the redirection URL is a part of the same domain, then you could try by giving referrel URL rather than giving full URL post the ajax calls.
i.e. rather than having "redirect('https://www.example.com/media/')", try by putting "redirect('/media/')". May be it can reduce the load time of the page.

Comment: Also, by looking at the 2nd screenshot, it seems your page is having mp4 video which is taking approximately 4 seconds to download. and its not in the first screenshot. Chances are there that video might be affecting page load time if heavy in size.

Comment: I've tried relative urls as mentioned in previous comments. and regarding video, that's not an issue as it's from previous page. And highlighted part is redirection which needs to be considered.

Comment: maybe a link can trigger browser prefetch a hidden link can test this and <meta http-equiv="Link" content="</images/big.jpeg>; rel=prefetch"> can enable prefetch. try $('#link').click() to replace location.href. make your service faster is more important, 3second is pretty long,keep alive/cache/cdn/http2/backend logic refine

Comment: @YanjunLin thanks for suggesting `prefetching`. I've tried `click` that has little bit good impact on loading speed, its better than window object based redirection.

Comment: @YanjunLin I have applied `prerender`ing in my other project and guess what, I can see significant improvement in performance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all the solutions provided in comments, thanks to all.
As per comment by @YanjunLin I have tried `click`ing element directly with jQuery rather than `window` object based redirection. And it worked.

However clicking method is faster by 60-70% than other methods for my application.

Anyone in future comes here try element clicking (`$('element selector').click()`) method, I hope that will work for you as well.

Please note that it is dependent on architecture of your application. It may happen that `Window.location.reload/assign` etc is faster for your application. But you can try this solution.

#### Update:

As per comment [`prefetching`](https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/) is also considerable factor if you have many static assets to load on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are suffering from caching by your web server. You can try to alter the cache settings via META tags, but you lose caching benefits. There is a simple trick I do that usually helps in all cases. Make the URL you are submitting unique by adding a timestamp to it. my_app.php?ts=1503710749
This uniqueness should cause immediate processing by your web server.